# Problem with MySqlCommand()

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005

I'm having a problem with `Dim query As New MySqlCommand("Select count(*)....")` I would like to take the variable `query` and do an `If query <> 1 Then` statement on it. Is this possible or is there a completely other way to go about this comparing the contents of a MySQL select statement. I'm rather new to Visual Basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `MySqlCommand` type doesn't return the results after construction, it just creates an object that can run queries. You must then *execute* the query:

```
Dim result as Integer
Using cn As New MySqlConnection("your connection string here"), _
      cmd As New MySqlCommand("Select count(*) ...", cn)

    cn.Open()
    result = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
End Using
```

Don't forget to [use query parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i) rather than string concatenation to substitute data into your sql statements.